# Vuetify 3 toolbar

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js

I am new to vuetify, and i need some help.

So, I have a `VToolbar` component that i need to set a height of `30px`.
The problem is, when i inpected in devtools, vuetify by default adds a `div`, `v-toolbar__content` and by default sets its height to 64px.

I tried overriding it with css, giving the `v-toolbar__content` a height but id does not work. The default vuetify value always overrides it.
Even gave `VToolbar`, the parent component the desired height, but `v-toolbar__content` overrides it.

Is there a way to set the desired height for the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the documentation.
I just added .

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-toolbar/

Comment: Please, copy the relevant information into the question. For more information, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/902374.